# for name in names: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, symbols

i'm having this issue of `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`in my code for writting a method inside a class named as `Qrely`and it takes some instances in the `__init__` method as following:`def __init__(self,ah=(),bh=(),av=(),bv=(),aph=(),bph=(), apv=(),bpv=()):`
the method where i'm having the issue is:

i've tried to change the type of instances by using the dispatch for example `ah:Tuple`but i get the same error

```py
 def qrelay_op(self,n, phi, alpha, delta):
        self.ah = symbols(print("a_H1={:d}".format(n + 1)))
        self.bh = symbols(print("b_H1={:d}".format(n + 1)))
        self.av = symbols(print("a_V1={:d}".format(n + 1)))
        self.bv = symbols(print("b_V1={:d}".format(n + 1)))
        op = 0

        for i in range(0,n-1):
            op += phi[i] * (self.ah[i]*self.bh[i] + self.av[i]*self.bv[i])

        B = 1/sqrt(2)*np.array([[1, 1],[-1, 1]])

        self.aph = symbols(print("a'_H1={:d}".format(n + 1)))
        self.bph = symbols(print("b'_H1={:d}".format(n + 1)))
        self.apv = symbols(print("a'_V1={:d}".format(n + 1)))
        self.bpv = symbols(print("b'_V1={:d}".format(n + 1)))

        for i in range(0,n-1):
            op = np.transpose(op, self.bh[i], self.ah[i+1], self.bph[i], self.aph[i+1], B)
            op = np.transpose(op, self.bv[i], self.av[i+1], self.bpv[i], self.apv[i+1], B)

        op = np.transpose(op, self.ah[0], self.av[0], self.aph[0], self.apv[0], self.rotatmatrix(alpha))
        op = np.transpose(op, self.bh[n-1], self.bv[n-1], self.bph[n-1], self.bpv[n-1], self.rotatmatrix(delta))

        syms = Qrely(self.ah, self.bh, self.av, self.bv, self.aph, self.bph, self.apv, self.bpv)

        return syms, op
```

when i test the code for example:
`A=Qrely()
print(A.qrelay_op(3, np.array([np.pi, np.pi/2, np.pi/5]), np.pi/4, np.pi/3))`
i get this error:
`line 693, in symbols for name in names:TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`
i can(t find this none type object in my code or i'm missing something even everything seems fine to me

Comment: When you don't show us the code that fails, it's very difficult to help you...

Comment: Presumably, `names` is None instead of a list

Comment: @alfasin this is the only part of the code where i'm having the issue currently because i have tested the other methods and they are working and that part in it self is a code that you can run as i said in the question just put it inside a `Class`where the `__init__` method has these instances `def __init__(self,ah=(),bh=(),av=(),bv=(),aph=(),bph=(), apv=(),bpv=()):`

Comment: You ask about an error in a line of code but you show us a different part of the code. I honestly don't know what to say...

Comment: @BenJ. yes but that in sympy package of the traceback and since i'm using PyCharm i can see the package but i got no idea why i'm getting this error

Comment: and which line in your code calls sympy? (and fails)

Comment: @alfasin the error occurs in line 35, in `qrelay_op self.ah = symbols(print("a_H1={:d}".format(n + 1)))`

Comment: if you want me to post the entire code i'm okay with that @BenJ.

Answer (score 1):

If you're saying that `self.ah = symbols(print("a_H1={:d}".format(n + 1)))` is the issue we need to understand what `symbols` is doing.

It *looks* like `symbols` wants you to pass it something iterable, but instead you're passing it the output of the `print()` function which is `None`.

```
>>> a = print('Sample Text')
>>> print(a)
None
```

Try changing

```
self.ah = symbols(print("a_H1={:d}".format(n + 1)))
```

to

```
self.ah = symbols("a_H1={:d}".format(n + 1))
```

Comment: i just did it and tried to run it again but this time i get a `TypeError: 'Symbol' object does not support indexing`, the error occurs this time in in `op += phi[i] * (self.ah[i]*self.bh[i] + self.av[i]*self.bv[i])`

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish here. As far as the syntax, `self.ah[i]` is trying to get the first element of `self.ah` which is a single `Symbol`. But you can't do that, because that's not how a single `Symbol` works. There is insufficient code here to fix this.

Comment: Okay what I'm trying to achieve from the first 4 lines is to give me a list of string separated By space to create a list of symbols  the length of this list will be `n` and then use the loop `for i in range ( 0,n-1) to execute the ` op += phi[i] * (self.ah[i]*self.bh[i] + self.av[i]*self.bv[i])`  and get a list of symbols in aph and both....

Comment: the output that is expected is something like in julia language we can do this: `ah= symbols(@sprintf("a_H1:%d",4)` and the output will be `(a_H1, a_H2, a_H3,a_H4)`

Comment: `output = [symbols('a_H{}'.format(i)) for i in [1,2,3,4]]`